# TypeLoadException was unhandled after reimporting images in resources

Tags: c#, exception, unhandled, typeloadexception

I'm getting this error after reimporting 2 images in resources.

```
TypeLoadException was unhandled

An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occured in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not load type
'WindowsFormsApplication3.LauncherTest' from assembly
'WindowsFormsApplication3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral
```

I might just have lost my entire work, please help me.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "reimporting"? What have you done exactly?

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes Deleted and imported into resources again.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem,

For people having this error, I suggest to carefully read their code for things which were not supposed to be there. Also, don't include more libraries than necesary.